# Add figure-like linespacing after minipage

Tags: spacing, captions, minipage, line-spacing

To resize images and include them as figures I've been using minipages like this

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering\captionsetup{type=figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image.png}
    \captionof{figure}{There is an image here}
\end{minipage}
```

When inserted into the document it finds itself crammed right up against the rest of the text, there is no breathing room between the caption and the next paragraph.

[image]

But I would like it to always have the same spacing as a table caption

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
One & Two & Three \\
Four & Five & Six \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is nicely padded.}
\end{center}
```

[image]

How can I do it without manually adding `\vspace` family commands every time?

Comment: I would put the minipage in a center environment that is the standard latex display environment spacing, which is what you want if not floating the figure

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that seems to have worked, Would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the `minipage` in a `center` environment, that is the standard latex display environment spacing, which is what you want if not floating the figure.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX2e uses the length `\intextsep` for the spacing of floats. Quote from `source2e.pdf`:

> `\intextsep`: Space left on top and bottom of an in-text float.

You can define your own environment, that acts like a non-floating `figure`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nonfigure}
  {%
    \par
    \vspace\intextsep
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \def\@captype{figure}%
  }
  {%
    \end{minipage}%
    \par
    \vspace\intextsep
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindduck
\begin{nonfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{a duck}
\end{nonfigure}
\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I set it up to be the same as the table?

Comment: @theonlygusti see my edit.